# how to fix? create react app on windows doesn't work

Tags: create-react-app

when i create react up it keeps showing me this error "npm ERR! code E400" ,"npm ERR! 400 Bad Request" please what should i do

i just updated nodejs and tried to create react app with and without 'create-react-app' but still shows this error

npx create-react-app new_app
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\OWN-IT\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-11T07_40_16_100Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\OWN-IT\Documents\react>

Comment: Can you share the content of that log file?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Nodejs are you using?

Im recommend the latest LTS release.

Check out the version first.

If you're already latest LTS release, try this solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65822052

Comment: the verstion is   v19.0.1

Comment: That was not latest LTS release. I recommend that you delete that and reinstall it as 18.12.1.