Node JS issue 400 bad request on npm install
% npm i
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@testing-library%2freact

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/smadeleri/.npm/_logs/2024-04-02T08_41_38_863Z-debug-0.log

What should be done to fix this error?

Do you set https-proxy? try npm config rm https-proxy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62130551/problem-with-npm-install-npm-err-code-e400 may solve this error

@YuMiao
Thanks, yes i am using proxy since i am on a vpn, and i am using a Mac machine, so the above solution doesnt work.
cafile = "/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/combined_cacerts.pem"
proxy = "https://npm.paypal.com/"
python = "python3"
registry = "https://npm.paypal.com/"
scope = "@paypalcorp"

Does the error still exist after trying to turn off the VPN?

No its still the same

yes its still the same, with or without vpn (without vpn, i tried with npm org registry and papal registry both)
